# UPDATE please look again - CSRF token mismatch server (local its working fine?!)

Tags: php, session, authentication, system, token

I didn't post any code because its 1000+ lines code and I didn't know where to search. Now I finally found the 'error line', so hopefully this post can be voted up.

When I submit data in my form, it should be running php code to check the data with the data in the database. Local, it works fine. On server not.

When I run the website local and press F5, it print a boolean false. When I hit the Submit button, it print a boolean true.

When I run the website on the server and press F5, it print a boolean false. BUT when I hit the Submit button, it print a boolen FALSE instead of true!

Reason for this: the token set in the session on the server is not the same token as sent by hitting the submit button. That's why an if statement doesn't run.

login.php

```
<?php
require_once("core/init.php");
require "/templates/header.php"; 
?>
<div id="text"> <?php

    if(Input::exists()) {
        var_dump(Token::check(Input::get("token"))); //on server always false!
        print_r(Input::get("token")); //(because this is something different then the token in the session, see code token class)
        //if(Token::check(Input::get("token"))) {
            $validate = new Validate();
            $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
                "username" => array("required" => true),
                "password" => array("required" => true)
                ));

            if($validation->passed()) {
                $user = new User();

                $remember = (Input::get("remember") === "on") ? true : false;
                $login = $user->login(Input::get("username"), Input::get("password"), $remember);

                if($login) {
                    Redirect::to("index.php");
                }
                else {
                    echo "Sorry, logging in failed."; 
                }
            }
            else {
                foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                    echo $error, "<br>";
                }
            }
        //}
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post"> 
        <div class="field">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="remember">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">Remember me
            </label>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Log in">
    </form> 

</div>
```

Token class

```
class Token{
    public static function generate() {
        return Session::put(Config::get("session/token_name"), md5(uniqid()));
    }

    public static function check($token) {
        //check if token excists in the session
        $tokenName = Config::get("session/token_name"); //get tokenname 
print_r(Session::get($tokenName)); //local they are the same, on server not!
print_r($token);

        if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) { 
            //check if session exists with token 
            Session::delete($tokenName); //delete, dont need anymore
            return true;
        }



        return false; 
    }

}
```

Comment: I made some cookies at home. They tasted fine at home, but once i reached my place of work, they were not edible. What is the problem?

Comment: given the "no code" or any other information, all I can say is *check for errors*.

Comment: Can we please have some more information, you telling us something works in one place and not the other, does not tell us anything.

Comment: Did the cookies set on the server, if not how do you set the cookies - double check on domain that you use on setting cookies

Comment: @bIgBoY this is a nice sentence, we get a lot of this situations in here, but this is very very nice and funny :)

Comment: @Franco upvote ;) cheers!

Comment: I can post code, but it's a lot... I worked with classes for database, hash, token, validation, cookie, config etc etc.. That's why I didn't post code, I was hoping that someone could tell where to start checking for errors or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to check out all links properly which you put in action attribute of the form, or may be some other links.

I don't think there is any cookies related issue is there, unless you used it additionally.